# building a sql query string with php parameters

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to do this, but it returns null?

```
$query_1=$field_name[0]."='{".$field_value[0]."}'";
```

and then

```
getType = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wines WHERE $query_1") or die(mysql_error());
```

while if i do like this:

```
 $getType = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wines WHERE $field_name[0]='{$field_value[0]}'") or die(mysql_error());
```

it works fine.

is this even possible, or am I missing something too obvious?
thank you in advance!

Comment: The solution is in the answers below, but you should really be aware that there is a high risk of SQL injection if you do it this way. Please sanitize your input before using it directly in a SQL query like this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are building it the wrong way. You should never use curly brackets (or any other string) in a SQL query. Concatenate your query instead.

Like this:

```
$query_1=$field_name[0]."='".$field_value[0]."'";
```

and oh, you missed a $ before your query, thats why its null.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
$field_name[0] = "test";
$field_value[0] = "someting";
$query_1=$field_name[0]."='".$field_value[0]."'";
echo ("SELECT * FROM wines WHERE $query_1") or die(mysql_error());
```

Hope it helps